# Blender normal Shader not working

Tags: shaders

I wanted a wave texture to convert to normal but it has a problem.

This is what I want:

[image]

And it gives me this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the texture you are trying to use is a B&W image, not a *purple* (tangent space) normal map, you should be using a **Bump Node** instead of a **Normal Map Node**. Connect the wave texture to the Height input of the Bump Node, and then connect the Normal output of the Bump Node like you would with a Normal Map. Additionally, I often find the contrast between black and white on many of the generated textures to be too strong to make a realistic bump map on it's own. I find that using a MixRGB node, to mix the results of the generated map with white (or black), helps to soften the impact of the texture and make the resulting bump map look more realistic. This can also be done by controlling the strength factor of the Bump Node, however I feel this way gives me more control, especially when using multiple generated textures at once.

[image]

Comment: thanks, man! appreciated